# How inject logger object from .Net Core Worker Service into .Net Standard Library Class

Tags: logging, .net-core, worker

I have created a Worker Service in .Net Core and a class library in .NET standard.
The DI in My worker looks like this :

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                IConfiguration configuration = hostContext.Configuration;
                services.AddSingleton<IAdoSqlServerAccesss, AdoSqlServerAccesss>(serviceProvider =>
                   {
                       return new AdoSqlServerAccesss(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
                   });
                services.AddSingleton<ISqlServerDataExtract, SqlServerDataExtract>();
                services.AddSingleton<IGetRemainderInfo<RemainInfo>, GetRemainderInfo>();
                services.AddSingleton<ISendRemainder<RemainInfo>, SendRemainder>(serviceProvider =>
                {
                    return new SendRemainder(configuration.GetValue<string>("AppURL"), hostContext.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, configuration.GetValue<string>("SMTPHost"));
                });

                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            });
```

And like this:

```
 private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private readonly IGetRemainderInfo<RemainInfo> _getRemainInfo;
    private readonly ISendRemainder<RemainInfo> _sendRemain;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IGetRemainderInfo<RemainInfo> getRemainInfo, ISendRemainder<RemainInfo> sendRemain)
    {
        _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        _getRemainInfo = getRemainInfo ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(getRemainInfo));
        _sendRemain = sendRemain ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sendRemain));
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);                

            List<RemainInfo> ls = this._getRemainInfo.GetAppsToRemains("CA_Remain_Applications");
            this._sendRemain._logger = _logger;
            this._sendRemain.SendDSRRemainderEmails(ls);
            this._sendRemain.SendDSMRemainderEmails(ls);
            await Task.Delay(360000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
```

All the functionality of the worker is inside the classes that I have in the class library.
Then in the worker I call this function from my class library and I need to use the logger in this function, but I'm not sure how to pass the logger instance through DI from the worker project to the class library :

```
 public void SendDSRRemainderEmails(List<RemainInfo> lst)
    {
        try
        {
            _logger?.LogInformation("DoSometing INFO message");

            var onlyDsr = from info in lst
                          where info.DSR_EMAIL != ""
                          group info by info.Number;

            MailModel mailinfo = new MailModel();
            //iterate each group        
            foreach (var dsrGroup in onlyDsr)
            {
                string Apps = "";
                foreach (var s in dsrGroup)  //Each group has a inner collection  
                {
                    Apps += s.CORPORATION_NAME + "<br/>";
                }
                String body = Utils.GetApplicationTemplateBody(_pathproject + Utils.RemainDSRTemplatePath);
                List<string> To = new List<string>();
                To.Add(dsrGroup.First().DSR_EMAIL);
                body = body.Replace("{SendSubject}", "Remainder of the Applications that you have pending of action");
                body = body.Replace("{DSRNAME}", dsrGroup.First().Name + ", yu have these applications pending of an action by you or your client:");
                body = body.Replace("{LISTOFAPPLICATIONS}", Apps);
                body = body.Replace("{ApplicationURL}", _applicationurl);
                mailinfo.To = To;  // From = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendNotificationsFromMailID"]
                mailinfo.Subject = Utils.RemainSubject;
                mailinfo.Body = body;
                Utils.SendMail(mailinfo, _smtpHost);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _logger?.LogError("ERROR in SendDSRRemainderEmails: " + ex.Message + ( ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.Message : "") );
            // Test logs at each level
            /*   _logger?.LogTrace("DoSometing TRACE message");
               _logger?.LogDebug("DoSometing DEBUG message");
               _logger?.LogInformation("DoSometing INFO message");
               _logger?.LogWarning("DoSometing WARN message");
               _logger?.LogCritical("DoSometing CRITICAL message"); */
        }
                  
         
    }
```

Comment: Maybe the type of the logger from within the service is of type ILogger without any template or you can inject inside the service another logger `ILogger<SendRemainderRemainInfo>`

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out my problem, here the solution is very simple :
In the worker side :

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                IConfiguration configuration = hostContext.Configuration;
                services.AddSingleton<IAdoSqlServerAccesss, AdoSqlServerAccesss>(serviceProvider =>
                   {
                       return new AdoSqlServerAccesss(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
                   });
                services.AddSingleton<ISqlServerDataExtract, SqlServerDataExtract>();
                services.AddSingleton<IGetRemainderInfo<RemainInfo>, GetRemainderInfo>();
                services.AddSingleton<ISendRemainder<RemainInfo, MailModel>, SendRemainder>(serviceProvider =>
                {
                    var logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<SendRemainder>>();
                    return new SendRemainder(configuration.GetValue<string>("AppURL"), hostContext.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, 
                                             configuration.GetValue<string>("SMTPHost"), configuration.GetValue<string>("From"), logger);
                });

                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            });
}
```

In the class library side :

```
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public SendRemainder(string creditappurl, string pathproject, string smtpHost, string from, ILogger<SendRemainder> logger)
    {
        this._applicationurl = creditappurl;
        this._pathproject = pathproject;
        this._smtpHost = smtpHost;
        this._From = from;
        _logger = logger;
    }
```

The Solution was very simple, in the worker side i just added this line of code inside the creation of the class from the class library where i need to log something :

```
var logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<SendRemainder>>();<br>
```

Then I passed this variable over the contructor of the class from the class library :

```
return new SendRemainder(configuration.GetValue<string>("AppURL"), hostContext.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, 
                                             configuration.GetValue<string>("SMTPHost"), configuration.GetValue<string>("From"), logger);
```